# right way to call socket from constructor function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, es6-class

I have a class like down below in a nodejs project. And I passed the socket from the client to the User class itself. But when writing receive statements (is this the name of them?), I get this error.

```
class User {
   constructor(stats) {
      this.name = stats.name;
      // passing socket to class User
      this.sock = stats.socket;
   }
   this.sock.on("doStuff", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
   });
}
```

The problem is, vscode hints me that:

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

So does that mean I should move `this.sock.on(???);` up inside the constructor function? What is the best practice to this problem?

Comment: I will personally move it into the constructor - otherwise you can also create a function like `setupSocket()` (to call on the instance just created) and put it there but i don't like this approach in this particular case